# Install NAS4Free on embedded linux

Tags: linux, operating-systems, embedded

My device has two usb ports and a a/b port, an ethernet port and some audio-video ports.I also can access it via Telnet (PuTTY).

I want to install this OS, can i ? and how ?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Emtec Q800 (as indicated in your other question [Change OS with A/B cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/1188198/change-os-with-a-b-cable)) is not able to load the NAS4Free operating system.

The NAS4Free OS is designed to be loaded onto a PC that you are building out for the purpose of being a NAS.  But it isn't made for replacing the embedded OS on existing single-purpose hardware.  To install NAS4Free you need to be able to boot the PC from the NAS4Free install media, and to write to the PCs primary storage (not NAS storage) to overwrite/install the new OS.

Comment: Sooo, does that mean i cant install any OS on that device ?

Comment: Any alternate OS that you wish to install on that device will need to have an installer made specifically for Emtec Q800 firmware.  Consider it like a modern automobile; there is a computer made from standard components that runs the auto, but it will only run AutoManufactureOS.  I can't load Ubuntu on my automobile's computer, even though they have the same basic parts, because the auto's computer needs its OS loaded a special way into a special part of its primary storage.  I can [maybe] upgrade to AutoManufactureOS 2.0, but I can't even change to CompetingManufactureOS, much less OpenSource

Comment: Daamn.... okay then. Thanks for all, you have help me loads!! I have been with this project for two entire weeks