# Change OS with A/B cable?

Tags: linux, networking, operating-systems, chipset

I have this machine with embedded linux, and it has an A/B port, so i can connect it directly to my PC. I would like to change the OS on this device, and as I have tried many different ways, this cable could solve my problem. I know Arduino boards are connected to PC with this cable, so may it be possible to connect my device to the pc this way ? This is an EMTEC device, if this is important

THX

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "A/B port"?  Also, what is the exact model of the device (that can matter in determining if the embedded OS is changeable and how to do so)

Comment: A/B port is the cable to connecct   the printer, if i'm not wrong... My device is running BusyBox v1.1.3 (2008.12.25-02:18+0000) multi-call binary

Comment: You're talking about a USB type-A (flat like where you plug a thumb drive into a computer) and a USB type-B (an almost squared hexagon, like the port on most USB printers).  Gottcha.  I'm assuming your Emtec device has a type-B plug on it, which simply means is can be plugged into a PC (if it has a type-A, it means you can plug other things into it).  That doesn't necessarily mean anything about its capability to receive a new OS.  The device model would help a good deal in determining that.  What device is it (if I wanted to buy one myself, what would I be buying)?

Comment: It's an old device. EMTEC Q800.
I didn't mean that type-B port was to give a new OS, just wondering if i could manipulate something that way haha
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Emtec Q800 is not able to load the NAS4Free operating system (as indicated in your other question [Install NAS4Free on embedded linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1188181/install-nas4free-on-embedded-linux)).

The NAS4Free OS is designed to be loaded onto a PC that you are building out for the purpose of being a NAS.  But it isn't made for replacing the embedded OS on existing single-purpose hardware.  To install NAS4Free you need to be able to boot the PC from the NAS4Free install media, and to write to the PCs primary storage (not NAS storage) to overwrite/install the new OS.